# Symfony query syntax

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I have question or problem with query syntax. I have 2 entity tables related with `ManyToMany`:

**Person.php**

```
/**
 * @ORM/ManyToMany(targetEntity="Deal", inversedBy="persons")
 * @ORM/JoinTable(name="persons_deals")
 * /
 protected $deals;
```

**Deal.php**

```
/*
 * @ORM/ManyToMany(targetEntity="Person", mappedBy="deals")
 * /
protected $persons;
```

This creates an "extra" table called `persons_deals` in the database.
In that table is 
**"person_id"** and **"deal_id"**

If a deal is done there is (for example):

```
  person_id ---- deal_id

    1 -------------- 1 
    2 -------------- 1
```

So if I want to get **deal_id 1** and **persons** connected to it.
What kind of query should I make?

Comment: You should look into Doctrine (which this is using). You don't really work with SQL or tables, you work with objects and classes. $person->setDeal($deal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is covered in the documentation.

[Joining Related Records in Symfony2](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#joining-related-records)

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as Symfony Query Language (or Syntax).
You are probably talking about Doctrine.

So it's better covered at Doctrine documentation how to organize many-to-many relation.

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional

Pay your attention, you'll probably have to fix namespaces from example to make it work at your code

So instead

- @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Group")
- @JoinTable(name="users_groups",

you will need to make

- @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Group")
- @ORM\JoinTable(name="users_groups",